# "Strange" reputation increase

Tags: discussion

This is not a question, It's an answer.
In case you woke up and you found your reputation on this website (or any other stackexchange website) significantly increased compared to the last time you were here, don't panic.
It's a feature, not a bug:
**TL;DR:** Stackexchange has increased the number of points you receive for an upvote on a question from 5 to 10. This was done retroactively. So for  every <sup>*</sup> upvote you got on a question in the past you received 5 extra points.

**Long version:** https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/

<sup>*</sup> The daily limit of 200 points still applies. So there may be questions for which you did not get the extra 5 points.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! your answer always helps out whether it's technical or normal question :)

Comment: That is a good news. We can gain more reputation. All fun.

Comment: Strange, someone down vote this post as well